# Nextjs - Children in WPGraphQL query for menus are null

Tags: graphql, next.js, apollo-client, wp-graphql

WPGraphiQL IDE displays correct data like this:

[image]

but when I make the same query with Apollo Client on the Front-End the children of menu returns null.

**Getting data with query**

```
import { useApollo } from "../lib/apolloClient";
import { initializeApollo } from "../lib/apolloClient";
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";
function CustomApp({ pageProps, Component, props }) {
  const apolloClient = useApollo(pageProps.initialApolloState);
  return (
    <>
      {console.log(props)}
    </>
  );
}

CustomApp.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const apolloClient = initializeApollo();

  await apolloClient.query({
    query: gql`
      {
        menu(id: 2, idType: DATABASE_ID) {
          id
          databaseId
          name
          slug
          menuItems {
            nodes {
              databaseId
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  });

  return {
    props: {
      initialApolloState: apolloClient.cache.extract(),
    },
  };
};
```

**Console:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdMVY.png

All other nodes return children without any problem.

Comment: auth/user role/capabilities problem? ... graphiql in admin works with admin role ... test 'externally' using f.e. postman then code

Comment: I tried and unfortunately result is still the same

Comment: tested using admin cookie/token?

Comment: It works!! using postman's cookie as you said. Thanks!

Comment: But how could I fix this for apollo client? I want response in NextJS

Comment: read apollo auth docs?

Answer (score 1):

WPGraphQL will return `null` for menus when queried externally (but they will work fine in GraphiQL) if the menu is not assigned to a menu location in the theme. Go from the `Edit Menus` tab to the `Manage Locations` tab and assign the menu to a theme location. Otherwise it's almost like the menu is a draft, and isn't externally accessible.

Here is a bug report that helped me, and states the same solve:
https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql/issues/1661